# using @ng-idle/core globally without the login page using it

Tags: angular, ionic2, ng-idle

I have a situation in ionic 2/angular2 i really do not know how to handle it, and would either need some sort of advice of a better way, or guide on my codes.

I have an app.component file which is defined as below (this is just a sample to just understand where i am going to)

```
 import {  Page1,LoginPage }  from '../pages/pages';
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

 import {Idle, DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES} from '@ng-idle/core';
 import {Keepalive} from '@ng-idle/keepalive';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

public pages = [
{
  title: 'Page 1', // I want when the user is on this page or other pages except Login, to sign the user out on Idle state
  icon: 'apps',
  count: 0,
  component: Page1
}]
rootPage: any = LoginPage;

 idleState = 'Not started.';
 timedOut = false;
 lastPing?: Date = null;

 constructor(public platform: Platform,
          public statusBar: StatusBar, 
          public splashScreen: SplashScreen,
          public _menuController: MenuController,
          private idle: Idle, 
          private keepalive: Keepalive){
   this.initializeApp();



idle.setIdle(5);

idle.setTimeout(5);

idle.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);

idle.onIdleEnd.subscribe(() => this.idleState = 'No longer idle.');
idle.onTimeout.subscribe(() => {
  this.idleState = 'Timed out!';
  this.timedOut = true;
});
idle.onIdleStart.subscribe(() => this.idleState = 'You\'ve gone idle!');
idle.onTimeoutWarning.subscribe((countdown) => this.idleState = 'You will 
 time out in ' + countdown + ' seconds!');

keepalive.interval(15);

keepalive.onPing.subscribe(() => this.lastPing = new Date());

this.reset();
 }


  reset() {
this.idle.watch();
this.idleState = 'Started.';
this.timedOut = false;
  }

}
```

According to the code above, when my screen is idle i set this.idleState to indicate idle state. But now i have a login page and may be 10 pages (in this example i have 1), and i need a situation when the user is idle i pop the user back to root (Login). My question is do i need to repeat the block of code in the constructor above on ALL PAGES and log my users out from there or can i create a helper class and inject it in ALL pages.I need an advice or a work around

Comment: Is this plugin working for you on an actual device? I can't get any events to fire but it works great in browser.

Comment: @Dexter did you find any better solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Well its not called a "helper class" per se', it is more a "service" that you can create to import into the page as required. Because your code does not have any specific view association but rather acts on a view/component it is a service of each view/component association. Whereas if it had view elements and logic based on view interactions you would then create a component.

I cant really tell what is going on with the code but all services are basically the same in that you imported re-usable code snippets from one source of truth.

So if you create you service `providers/handle-idle-service.ts` you then need to declare the service in your `app.module.ts` under `providers`

```
import { HandleIdle } from '../providers/handle-idle-service`;

....

providers: [
 { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
 StatusBar,
 SplashScreen,
 HandleIdle
]
```

This declares your service usable throughout the project which can then be imported in each pages component, were needed, for use.

```
import { HandleIdle } from '../providers/handle-idle-service`;
```

Check out the documentation on angular.io* for specific integration of services. Because Ionic is build on angular ( as i am sure you know ) the exact same principles apply.

*[Serivies REF](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)